# How to hide UI elements in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

I'd like to ask a case when developing a game using Unity.

There are many UI elements in the game.

These UI elements normally disappear from scenes when the purpose is achieved.

However, the `Destroy` or `SetActive` methods provided by Unity greatly affect game objects and sometimes lead to errors, especially when using coroutines, causing stability problems.

When making and using UI, is it standard and stable to use Alpha values of the UI's `Image`/panel component or `Text` component to make it disappear or appear?

Or is it standard and stable to use the `SetActive` function, passing true or false?

Comment: If `Destroy` or `SetActive` are leading to errors, you have written your code wrong, or made an error in your scene setup. API methods don't throw errors randomly — they obey a specific contract, and if you use them out of contract leading to unwanted behaviour, that's your error, and something you can fix. If you'd like help fixing those root problems, edit your question to document the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of one specific problem you've encountered when trying to use one of these methods.

Comment: thanks to reply, I know my design's problem. I tried to fix it but failed. The error was nullreception. I Initialized my variables, but using setActive or OnEnable() there is always error occured

Comment: You mean a Null Reference Exception. We have lots of Q&A about addressing those errors. They're not inherent to the use of `Destroy`, but a result of using it under the wrong mental model. If you edit your question to show us what you did, there's a good chance we can show you how to fix it.

Comment: It was an incredibly minor problem. I succeeded in resolving it, and after rebuilding it, we confirmed that the problem was resolved. Thank you for your help. It just gecomponentInchild problem ;(

Comment: If you've solved your problem, would you like to post your solution as an Answer, or delete this question?

Comment: thanks how can I make the comment to solution as an answer?

Comment: Scroll down.. There's a box labeled "Your Answer". Type your answer there. Be sure to include more detail than your comment, so that the answer would be useful to a fellow developer struggling with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DMGregory's comment is very useful thanks

> If Destroy or SetActive are leading to errors, you have written your code wrong, or made an error in your scene setup. API methods don't throw errors randomly — they obey a specific contract, and if you use them out of contract leading to unwanted behaviour, that's your error, and something you can fix. If you'd like help fixing those root problems, edit your question to document the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of one specific problem you've encountered when trying to use one of these methods

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you showed how you applied this advice to solve your problem.

Comment: I will do that next time. thanks

Comment: I recommend doing it this time, or your post may attract downvotes for not being very useful.